# Name error in object detection api in real time code

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection, nameerror, object-detection-api

File "", line 18, in  output_dict = run_inference_for_single_image(image_np, detection_graph)
NameError: name 'run_inference_for_single_image' is not defined.
This is the error i am getting by running the code from the below given github site i dont know how to debug that line.
[object detection github link](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection)

Can someone please help me to resolve this error?

Comment: You shared a github repo with thousand of line's code. It's very hard to help you, but I think you can find your answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49750520/run-inference-for-single-imageimage-graph-tensorflow-object-detection)

Comment: File "<ipython-input-7-e034ab310f6e>", line 18, in <module>
    output_dict = run_inference_for_single_image(image_np, detection_graph)  this is what the error is showing i dont know how to debug that line.